# Polymer 1.0 event => (event, detail, sender)

Tags: polymer

In Polymer 0.5 I could do this

```
public action(event, detail, sender){
   var help = sender.getAttribute('data-action');

   // do something with this value
}
```

I got this value in Polymer 1.0 too. But I think this is not the official
method

```
detail.sourceEvent.path[2].getAttribute('data-action')
```

Can somebody show me the official way ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution. Just write:

```
event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-action')
```